# WxWidgets with Mingw wx/msw/libraries.h: not found

Tags: c++

I'm using Debian 11, I installed Mingw and built WxWidgets with the following command:

```
../configure --prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-ming32 --build=x86_64-linux --with-msw && make && sudo make install
```

And I'm using the following command to build:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ wx.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags --libs std,aui`
```

I receive the following error:

```
wx/msw/libraries.h: not found
```

But file exists at: /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wx-3.2/wx/msw/libraries.h

Where am I going wrong?

PS: I don't use any kind of IDE.

Comment: Tell your compiler where to look for headers and libraries by providing it with the appropriate command line options specifying the correct search paths. Outside of the compilers default search locations, it will not magically discover stuff unless you help it.

Comment: If you run the command `wx-config --cxxflags --libs std,aui` by itself, what does it output?

Comment: wx-config --cxxflags --libs std,aui   
-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.2 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread
-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   -lwx_gtk3u_aui-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_html-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_qa-3.2 -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.2 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.2 -lwx_baseu_net-3.2 -lwx_baseu-3.2

Comment: I tried, x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ wx.cpp -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.2 -I/usr/local/include/wx-3.2 -L/usr/local/lib `wx-config --cxxflags --libs std,aui`, but i get the same error

Comment: Does anyone have any more tips?

Comment: Please don't add code or output in comments, ***[edit]*** your question instead. The `wx-config` output is almost impossible to read in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Friends, it finally worked, that's what you said above, the wx-config that is linked to the terminal, is only for linux, what was with the compilation for Windows inside /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin /wx-config.

When I want to compile for linux I pass:

```
g++ wx.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags --libs std,aui`
```

When I go to Windows I pass:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ wx.cpp `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config --cxxflags --libs std,aui`
```

PS: I had to copy some dlls to the application folder, but it all worked out.

Thank you very much for everyone's patience.